# Change boost thread priority in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, boost

Im trying to change the thread priority in boost but im having no luck. Im getting a bad handle error (type 6) from the GetLastError function. I though native_handle() returned the handle for the thread?

Any one know how to do this?

```
void baseThread::applyPriority(uint8 priority)
{

#ifdef WIN32
    if (!m_pThread)
        return;

    BOOL res;
    HANDLE th = m_pThread->native_handle();

    switch (priority)
    {
    case REALTIME   : res = SetPriorityClass(th, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);      break;
    case HIGH       : res = SetPriorityClass(th, HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS);          break;
    case ABOVE_NORMAL   : res = SetPriorityClass(th, ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);  break;
    case NORMAL     : res = SetPriorityClass(th, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);            break;
    case BELOW_NORMAL   : res = SetPriorityClass(th, BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);  break;
    case IDLE       : res = SetPriorityClass(th, IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS);          break;
    }

    if (res == FALSE)
    {
        int err = GetLastError();
    }

#endif
}
```

edit: Final code:

```
void baseThread::applyPriority(uint8 priority)
{

#ifdef WIN32
    if (!m_pThread)
        return;

    BOOL res;
    HANDLE th = m_pThread->native_handle();

    switch (priority)
    {
    case REALTIME       : res = SetThreadPriority(th, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);   break;
    case HIGH           : res = SetThreadPriority(th, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);         break;
    case ABOVE_NORMAL   : res = SetThreadPriority(th, THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);    break;
    case NORMAL         : res = SetThreadPriority(th, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);          break;
    case BELOW_NORMAL   : res = SetThreadPriority(th, THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL);    break;
    case IDLE           : res = SetThreadPriority(th, THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST);          break;
    }

#endif
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use SetThreadPriority function to set the thread priority. SetPriorityClass is used to set the priority of the process. You also have to change the priority values, see documentation for [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277(VS.85).aspx) for details.

Answer (score 3):

The `SetPriorityClass` function takes as it's first parameter a HANDLE, you are passing in a pointer to a HANDLE. Change it to:

```
res = SetPriorityClass(*th, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
```

or something equivalent. The kernel can tell that the pointer value you passed in isn't really a valid thread handle because I guess it maintains an internal list of currently allocated thread handles. The pointer obviously isn't in that list. The compiler can't really enforce better type safety, since a HANDLE is kind of an opaque type - you just have to be really careful what you pass in.

Oh by the way, the other commenter Dani is correct, `SetPriorityClass` is not used for setting the priority of a thread, you want to use `SetThreadPriority` anyway. But then my advice would still stand, you need to pass in a HANDLE, not a pointer to such.

Comment: The pointer thing was me messing with the code before hand and not fixing it up. But thanks for your help any way. :P