# Boost: how to set program priority?

Tags: c++, boost

How to set program/thread priority (when talking about threads I mean ones that are created using Boost library) using Boost C++ library? I mean crossplatform way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no generalised cross-platform priority support in boost itself.

`#ifdef` is your friend...

See Tom's answer for the win32 solution.

On Linux you'd use the [`nice`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nice) call (or possibly [`setpriority`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority)).  Don't be put off by those document's statements that they adjust *process* priority; on Linux a thread is just a process which shares a memory space with some other process/processes.  If you get yourself a better version of "top" which lists the individual threads, you can see the nice levels of each.

Note that a process/thread with normal user privileges can only *reduce* its priority (higher "nice" value) on Linux.  The little bit of work with priorities I've done on Windows, it seemed anything goes (but that was on XP; situation may be different post-Vista, UAC etc).

Comment: Similarly, in Windows the process priority class simply affects the thread priorities within that process - which are what really matter. Indeed, the entire concept of a process priority class can be misleading, as the scheduler of both Windows (and linux) is only looking at the effective thread priorities.

Answer (score 2):

[Change boost thread priority in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601337/change-boost-thread-priority)

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer's comment about Windows allowing users to change priorities to anything they want is partly correct, with a couple exceptions -- One, the Real Time priority class is normally not allowed (even with UAC elevation). It requires a special security token. That token is normally available to administrators though, but the process must request it.

Also, in Vista+ at least, *raising* the priority class of an external process is a right reserved only for Administrators in the default security policy. However, this only applies to EXTERNAL processes - so wouldn't affect your ability to set your own priority class.

Please keep in mind in Windows when you change the process priority class, you are changing the 'base' priority of all the threads in that process. You can leave the priority class at normal and adjust the priorities of specific threads as necessary (SetThreadPriority API vs SetPriorityClass API). This may be preferred for your *own* application.

I don't think this is the case here, but a warning -- if acting on an *external* process (not your own), *never* change the individual thread priorities of another process. Instead, only change the priority class so that all thread priorities retain the same relative difference to one another in scheduling importance.

There is no cross-platform way to do it because the behavior is so different. Conditional compile directives are, as the previous poster suggested, to be used in this situation.